# how to manage 2 stack query

Tags: sql, node.js, database, api

I have 2 query in a row Like this :

```
"SELECT A.id , A.name FROM A WHERE 1"

"SELECT b.val1, b.val2 FROM B WHERE B.id = result_from_A"
```

And result ID store in array

```
var JSON_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results_A));

for (let i = 0; i < JSON_obj.length; i++) {
    var A_Id = parseInt(JSON_obj[i].id);
    //query B from A_Id
}
```

And how to make data look like this

```
[{"name" : "...",
  "data":[
     {"val1":...},
     {"val2":...}]
 },
 {"name" : "...",
  "data":[
     {"val1":...},
     {"val2":...}]
 }]
```

Comment: what about use `JOIN` and have only 1 sql query. In result you can have `name, val1, val2`. And later format this data into json manually? Cause don't think your json format can be easily reached from your db data

Comment: which package you are using to handle sql query? Package must provide model relationship features. Model relationship is very handy to work such kind of data manipulation.